# Find products which have text equals either of the request

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my product indexed with the following

```
product_id | key | text   | number
1          | A1  | pc     | <null>
1          | A1  | mac    | <null>
1          | A2  | <null> | 23
1          | A2  | <null> | 30
2          | A1  | pc     | <null>
3          | A2  | <null> | 25
```

Now I want to find all the products where `key` = `A1` and `text` = `pc` AND `mac`
Which should give me `product 1`

How should by filter query look like ?

I have tried with

```
{  
   "bool":{  
      "must":[  
         {  
            "term":{  
               "key":{  
                  "value":"A1",
                  "boost":1
               }
            }
         },
         {  
            "term":{  
               "text":{  
                  "value":"mac",
                  "boost":1
               }
            }
         },
         {  
            "term":{  
               "text":{  
                  "value":"pc",
                  "boost":1
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

If I remove one of the `text` term, then it works fine.

I also tried with this

```
{  
   "bool":{  
      "filter":[  
         {  
            "terms":{  
               "product_id":[  
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "key":{  
                           "value":"A1",
                           "boost":1
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "text":{  
                           "value":"Mac",
                           "boost":1
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "key":{  
                           "value":"A1",
                           "boost":1
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "text":{  
                           "value":"Pc",
                           "boost":1
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My indexes are

```
text: { type: keyword, index: not_analyzed }
number: { type: float, index: not_analyzed }
product_id: { type: integer, index: not_analyzed }
key: { type: keyword, index: not_analyzed }
```

Comment: you need to index the key:text pairs as nested documents. If you can post your index mappings, it should help.

Comment: In your example you have the following condition -> where key = "A1" AND text="mac" AND text="pc" . This would never be true. Have you made a typo ? And what exactly mean A1 = pc ? These are values and not fields, right?

Comment: @ArchitSaxena yes, it would be the correct way, I totally understand that, but its unfortunate not possible.

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou sorry, that was a mistype. Updated my question

Comment: Martin you can post your mappings (as @ArchitSaxena asked you) with the GET /index/_mappings request

Comment: i don't think it can be done without changing the mapping in anyway TBH @EiriniGraonidou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your use case you can use terms query with aggregation

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "key": "A1"
               }
            },
            {
               "terms": {
                  "text": [
                     "mac",
                     "pc"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "BUCKET_NAME": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "product_id.keyword",
            "min_doc_count":2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

- product_id | key | text | number
- doc_1:   1 | A1  | pc   | __
- doc_2:   1 | A1  | mac| __
- doc_3:   1 | A2  | __   | 23
- doc_4:   1 | A2  | __   | 30
- doc_5:   2 | A1  | pc   | __
- doc_6:   3 | A2  | __   | 25

Above query first fetches all docs having **key** as "A1" and **text** either "mac" or "pc". So query first returns doc_1, doc_2, doc_5 having product_id respectively 1 ,1, 2. 
then it apply aggregation on **product_id** field with  "min_doc_count":2 So aggregation returns only product_id which comes atleast 2 times in query result. 
So final query end up getting desired "product_id" ("key" in agg bucket)

Now your result is in aggregation result. Hope this will help you

Comment: May I ask, why you added the aggregation?

Comment: `code`
product_id | key | text | number
doc_1:   1 | A1  | pc   | __
doc_2:   1 | A1  | mac| __
doc_3:   1 | A2  | __   | 23
doc_4:   1 | A2  | __   | 30
doc_5:   2 | A1  | pc   | __
doc_6:   3 | A2  | __   | 25

Above query first fetches all docs having **key** as "A1" and **text** either "mac" or "pc". query returns doc_1, doc_2, doc_5 having product_id respectively 1 ,1, 2. 
So when you aggregate on **product_id** field with  "min_doc_count":2 it returns only product_id which comes atleast 2 times in query result. 
So final query end up getting "product_id" as "key" in agg bucket

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong, but I think the requirement is only to find the matching products (and not restrict them). @Martin should answer this one. Your query is correct, I m not sure about the aggregation

Comment: @torzonhot Yours actually works perfect, but what when I also want to query key = A2 and number between 20 and 28 - how should the aggregation then look like?

Comment: @Martin In that case you need change query accordingly and remove "min_doc_count" from aggs.

Comment: @torzonhot Nope, that doesnt work :( - As i want both the A1 = mac,pc AND A2 between 20 and 28 - https://gist.github.com/lsv/73933e0e8bce039a9afde7c5ab12e664

Comment: @Martin now your question has been changed I think you should ask a separate question for this task

Comment: New question added, and you got a bounty @torzonhot becuase my initial question is answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446649/find-products-which-have-text-equals-and-is-between-a-range-of-the-request