# Find products which have text equals and is between a range of the request

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my product indexed with the following

```
product_id | key | text   | number
1          | A1  | pc     | <null>
1          | A1  | mac    | <null>
1          | A2  | <null> | 23
1          | A2  | <null> | 30
2          | A1  | pc     | <null>
3          | A2  | <null> | 25
4          | A2  | <null> | 32
4          | A1  | linux  | <null>
```

Now I want to find the products where

- `key` = `A1` and `text` is either `pc` or `mac`
- `key` = `A2` and `number` is between `22` and `28`

This should give me `product_id` `1`, `2` and `3`, but not product_id 4, because its not inside the range nor have A1 the selected key in `A1`

My indexes are

```
text: { type: keyword, index: not_analyzed }
number: { type: float, index: not_analyzed }
product_id: { type: integer, index: not_analyzed }
key: { type: keyword, index: not_analyzed }
```

The following works perfect, if only `text` are selected

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "key": "A1"
               }
            },
            {
               "terms": {
                  "text": [
                     "mac",
                     "pc"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "BUCKET_NAME": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "text",
            "min_doc_count":2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But if I put my range in, it does not work any more

Comment: What happens when you put the range part? Also please provide the query that includes the range part

Answer (score 0):

You can use your both conditions in a should clause like below and then simply apply aggregation.

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "key": "A1"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "text": [
                              "pc",
                              "mac"
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "key": "A2"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "range": {
                           "number": {
                              "gte": 22,
                              "lte": 28
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "PRODUCT_IDs": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "product_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
```